# Excel sum columns based on header date between range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I am trying to sum columns in the following example:

[image]

Based on their headers that should fall between two fixed dates. I have tried both SUMPRODUCT and SUMIFS formulas but my attempts return errors.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($C$10<=Q1Dates)*($D$10>=Q1Dates))*Table1[[4/1/2021]:[10/1/2021]])
```

Where Q1Dates is the range for the headers in the table, $C$10 and $D$10 are the two fixed dates and the Table1 range is the range I am attempting to sum.

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[[4/1/2021]:[10/1/2021]], Q1Dates, "<="&Sheet2!D10, Q1Dates, ">="&Sheet2!C10)
```

And above the SUMIFS attempt.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that the dates in the header are text that look like dates and not true dates. try this shot in the dark: `=SUMPRODUCT((($C$10<=--Q1Dates)*($D$10>=--Q1Dates))*Table1[[4/1/2021]:[10/1/2021]])`

Comment: Also the number of columns must match between `Q1Dates` and `Table1[[4/1/2021]:[10/1/2021]]`

Comment: Thank you. Based on your two comments I pieced together a solution using a second row below the headers with actual date formulas. I do wish there was an option to use formulas in table headers..